# I want to concatenate 1 st letter of firstname and lastname from my table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to concatenate first letter of First name and last  name from my table.my table field name is cname size varchar2(20).
my table is this

```
CNAME
-------------
JOHN XAVIER
ANU SAM
ANU SAM
Phil ober
vivek sundar
Xylona Preis
Xylona Preis
Darren WHITE
FRANCIS GEORGE
```

I tried this below query to get this output.
here is the query:

```
`select SUBSTR(CNAME,1,1)||SUBSTR(CNAME,(INSTR(CNAME,'')+1),1`) FROM SALES;
```

But i got output like this:

```
CNAME
------
J
A
A
P
V
X
X
D
F
```

I do not know it is because of the space.My expected output is this:

```
cname
-----
JX
AS
AS
Po
vs
XP
XP
DW
FG
```

Please help.

Comment: What happens if they have more than two parts to the name? Eg: Dave Benson-Philips or Jesus H Christ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query

```
select substr(cname,1,1) || substr(cname,instr(cname,' ')+1,1) 
from hkc_test;
```

works.

Note the SPACE between the ' and '

What are the back-quotes in your query ?

Comment: This would fail for a middle name, e.g. `John Parker Stevens`.

Comment: Thankyou.got the error,i did nt put brackets for instr.thank you for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which should work even if the name has any number of middle names or middle initials.  We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to find the first character of the name.  We can also use it to find the isolated last word in the name, presumably the last name.  Then, take the first character of that last name to get the initial.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('John Mark Xavier', '(\S)') ||
    SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR ('John Mark Xavier', '(\S*)$'), 1, 1) AS cname
FROM dual;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
UPPER(
  SUBSTR( CNAME, 1, 1 )
  || SUBSTR( CNAME, INSTR( CNAME, ' ', -1 ) + 1, 1 )
)
```

To get the first character of the first and last names or:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( CNAME, '(\w)\w*\W*', '\1' )
```

or

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( CNAME, '([A-Z])[A-Z'']*[^A-Z'']*', '\1', 1, 0, 'i' )
```

To get the first character of each name.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8e1c/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (CNAME) AS
SELECT 'JOHN XAVIER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANU SAM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANU SAM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Phil ober' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'vivek sundar' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Xylona Preis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Xylona Preis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Darren WHITE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRANCIS GEORGE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JOHN Smith-Smythe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RICHARD O''BRIEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GEORGE W BUSH' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT UPPER(
         SUBSTR( CNAME, 1, 1 )
         || SUBSTR( CNAME, INSTR( CNAME, ' ', -1 ) + 1, 1 )
       ) AS cname,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( CNAME, '([A-Z])[A-Z'']*[^A-Z'']*', '\1', 1, 0, 'i' ) AS cname2
FROM   Sales
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8e1c/2/0)**:

```
| CNAME | CNAME2 |
|-------|--------|
|    JX |     JX |
|    AS |     AS |
|    AS |     AS |
|    PO |     Po |
|    VS |     vs |
|    XP |     XP |
|    XP |     XP |
|    DW |     DW |
|    FG |     FG |
|    JS |    JSS |
|    RO |     RO |
|    GB |    GWB |
```

Comment: But what if the person has a middle name?  How about two middle initials (e.g. George H W Bush) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated